# Present Tab of TabBarController Through parent ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to present a certain index of my tabBarController but first go through another custom ViewController.

[image]

In the image above.  i want to present the yellow viewcontroller, which will automatically present my TabBar Controller, but i want the tab bar controller to show a specific index.

i present the yellow ViewController with the code below:

```
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tbc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
            tbc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.present(tbc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

normally when presenting a tab on a tabBarController i would use the following code:

```
let tbc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabController") as! UITabBarController

tbc.selectedIndex = 1
tbc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
tbc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
self.present(tbc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

how would i go about loading the specific index of the tab bar through the yellow viewcontroller?  it is a custom class with a custom segue:

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I would usually pass on the index you want from your yellow controller to the tabBarController (using let's say, an instance variable). Which then can be set by the tab bar controller to the index you want.